# laravel-twilio library to send voice message

Tags: video, laravel-5, twilio

In my laravel 5.6 application I use aloha/laravel-twilio library for sending sms message with method

```
$twilio->message('+18085551212', 'Pink Elephants and Happy Rainbows');
```

as it was written here https://github.com/aloha/laravel-twilio

It works ok, but I do not see if this library can send voice message( renter text in voice or recorded voice file ) ?

Are there some other laravel libraries for such tasks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The laravel-twilio package supports making calls too. As the [usage section in the README](https://github.com/aloha/laravel-twilio#usage) shows, you can either make a call and pass a URL:

```
$twilio->call('+18085551212', 'http://foo.com/call.xml');
```

That URL should then respond with [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) to tell Twilio what to do when the call is answered.

Alternatively, you can generate the call and the resulting message in one go like this:

```
$twilio->call('+18085551212', function ($message) {
    $message->say('Hello');
    $message->play('https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3', ['loop' => 5]);
});
```

It might also be of interest for you to take a look at the [Twilio PHP library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php) (which doesn't do anything special for Laravel, but should work in any framework) and the documentation for [making calls with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls).